# Flexbox basis not working if parent has column direction

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex container that has two children (a heading and a flex box). The direction of this container is column. The box children direction is **row** and I want to use flex-basis to constrain its **width**.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/alansouzati/pen/yXXrJm) for that.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 12px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-basis: 192px;
}
```

The problem is that flex-basis is changing the container's **height**, not the width. How to fix this?

Comment: You use `width`. `flex-basis` on a flex item in a column direction is its height

Comment: I know I can use width, but I would like to understand why this code is not working.

Comment: the direction is row. check the codepen.

Comment: The `flex-basis` is set on the flex item, not flex container, and in your case the flex container `container` has column direction. In your case the `flex-basis` you set does not respond to the flex direction set on the `box`, it respond to its parents flex direction, the `container`

Comment: got it, thanks! Can you post as answer so that I can accept it? I believe all I need is to set another flex box wrapper.  https://codepen.io/alansouzati/pen/VWWNdX

Comment: I did...and yes, that is how you can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flex-basis` property is set on the flex item, not flex container, and in your case the flex container `container` has column direction, hence `flex-basis` affect the height.

*Note, `flex-basis` you have in the `box` rule does not respond to the flex direction set on the `box`, it respond to its flex containers direction, the `container`*

---

With an extra wrapper it is possible though, which is set to row direction, to define the width using `flex-basis`: https://codepen.io/alansouzati/pen/VWWNdX